# File System data

Tags: json, node.js, filesystems, npm

So i'm starting to make a little widget that watches your filesystem for changes and I'm using npm's watch module, but a lot of the data is kind of obscured and I was hoping that someone could give me a good description of each of the parameters that are being returned by the module i'm using since there isn't much documentation about it.

```
{
    "dev": 16777223,
    "mode": 33204,
    "nlink": 1,
    "uid": 501,
    "gid": 20,
    "rdev": 0,
    "blksize": 4096,
    "ino": 23354217,
    "size": 4038,
    "blocks": 8,
    "atime": "2014-11-05T09:08:32.000Z",
    "mtime": "2014-11-05T09:08:51.000Z",
    "ctime": "2014-11-05T06:52:48.000Z",
    "birthtime": "2014-11-05T06:52:47.000Z"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "dev": 16777223,  //The device number containing the file.
  "mode": 33204,    //The mode of the file. This is an integer which incorporates file type information and file permission bits. See also stat:type and stat:perms below.
  "nlink": 1,       //The number of hard links to the file.
  "uid": 501,       //The user ID of the file’s owner.
  "gid": 20,        //The group ID of the file.
  "rdev": 0,        //Device ID; this entry is defined only for character or block special files.
  "blksize": 4096,  //The optimal block size for reading or writing the file, in bytes.
  "ino": 23354217,  //The file serial number, which distinguishes this file from all other files on the same device.
  "size": 4038,     //The size of a regular file in bytes.
  "blocks": 8,      //The amount of disk space that the file occupies measured in units of 512 byte blocks. 
  "atime": "2014-11-05T09:08:32.000Z", //The last access time for the file.
  "mtime": "2014-11-05T09:08:51.000Z", //The last modification time for the file.
  "ctime": "2014-11-05T06:52:48.000Z", //The last modification time for the attributes of the file.
  "birthtime": "2014-11-05T06:52:47.000Z" //The date where the file was created
}
```

Hope it helps!